# How to clear stacked chart without render

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have `barChart` with few stacks:

```
chart
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(group1, element1)
    .groupBars(true)
    .stack(group2, element2)
    .stack(group3, element3)
```

[image: stacked bar chart]

Later I add new dimension and groups to current chart:

```
chart
    .dimension(newDim)
    .group(newGroup1, newElement1)
    .groupBars(true)
    .stack(newGroup2, newElement2)

chart.redraw();
```

And get something strange:

[image]

Looks like the chart have green bars from previous stacks. If I do `chart.render()` instead of `chart.redraw()` all is ok, but `redraw()` looks much better. How can I fix this?

*UPDATE:*

I think I need to remove old dimension and/or groups from chart, but how can I do this?

Comment: Does ```chart.select("dim").remove();``` do anything better?

Comment: @ISOmetric I added this before second configuration of chart and have the same problem

Comment: Is there anything else you're doing there then? Could we see everything else you do between configurations?

Comment: @ISOmetric You pushed me to an idea, before second configuration I get new `crossfilter` object and new dimension is created from it. Can it be the problem?

Comment: Possibly - would be easier to tell if you added the code to your question.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, `crossfilter` is the same object. I haven't additional code :( just create new dimension and groups and use them in second chart configuration as I wrote in the question.

Comment: Maybe rather than trying to just remove that first dimension, you could remove everything from the chart by doing: ```chart.selectAll("*").remove()```

Comment: This is the bad idea )))

Comment: I think this may be a bug in the grouped bars feature, which is not yet released in dc.js. It looks like it needs to remove any non-existent "stacks" when it redraws, but it does not. Which version are you using, the Kavanagh version or the Gazal version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess because you haven't provided code.

As I commented above, I thought it was a bug in the implementation of grouped bars you are using.

But actually, I think it's a bug in dc.js core: it's not expecting the number of stacks to change without a render. I found a reference to the bug [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1039). (There was originally a lot of things that only worked for render, not redraw, and we're slowly patching those.)

Try this when you replace the stacks:

```
for(var i = nstacks; i < 20; ++i) 
    chart.selectAll('g.stack._' + i + ' rect').remove()
```

where `nstacks` is the number of stacks in the new chart. It will remove any excess stacks, and the existing ones should still transition okay.

Comment: Thanks, now I use `chart.selectAll("g.stack").remove()` before add new configuration.

Comment: Sure, that will force dc.js to render the bars over again, so you'll lose the transitions on any existing bars. If you're replacing all the data, the transitions may not make sense anyway.